# How to control the width of UITableView tableHeaderView?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview

I set the width of tableHeaderView's frame to 0, and the height is 60. But I do not know why the header width will match the table. Help!!
    `override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad() tableView.tableHeaderView = .init(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 60.0)) }`
and how I can set the width less than the tableview?
So I have a idea, we can use a parent view to match the header view, it will match the width, and then we can add the subview which is the real one we want to show, this subview's width can be controlled. like this:

```
        let sectionHeader = UIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 50))
        sectionHeader.backgroundColor = .yellow
        let label = UIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        label.backgroundColor = .brown
        sectionHeader.addSubview(label)
        return sectionHeader
```

is it right?

I want to know the principle of the phenomenon

Comment: As you have seen, the width of the `.tableHeaderView` is set to the width of the tableView. When you change the width of the table (such as on device rotation), the header view will automatically resize to the new width. So, yes... you should use subviews and constraints to layout the *content* of your header view.